# LuaBridge getGlobal is always returning nil

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I did a first small test with LuaBridge 1 week ago and it worked to get an int from the script.

Now I deleted this code and tried to include Lua script in my game engine but it is no longer working.
I tried to go back to a basic code with this :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "lua5.2/lua.hpp"
#include "LuaBridge/LuaBridge.h"

using namespace luabridge;


int main()
{
    lua_State* L;
    L = luaL_newstate();

    if(!luaL_loadfile(L, "../../script.lua"))
        std::cout << "failed loading" << std::endl;

    LuaRef s = getGlobal(L, "nmbr");
    int luaInt = s.cast<int>();
    std::cout << luaInt << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with this script

```
nmbr = 30
```

And it gives me :

```
PANIC: unprotected error in cell to Lua API (bad argument #2 (number expected, got nil))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It the same when I tried to get a string or a function from the script and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in this.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`luaL_loadfileex`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_loadfilex):

> As lua_load, this function only loads the chunk; it does not run it.

What that means is that the script is loaded, but it haven't been executed so there is really no variable `nmbr` to get. You need to run the script first for the code to work (for eample by calling [`lua_call`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_call)).

This is shown very well in the first simple example [in this LuaBridge tutorial](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/using-lua-with-cpp-luabridge/).

Comment: Yes I read this tutorial (and it's the reason it worked in the first place as I nearly copy-pasted it). But I had a bad understanding of the difference between dofile and loadfile. Now with your and @Youka 's answer I understood the issue and the need for the variable assignment. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`luaL_loadfile` ~= `luaL_dofile`. You load the script and get it as function on the stack but don't execute it, so the global assignment doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, I knew it was different but I just thought that the difference was that in dofile it would call the functions present in the script. I didn't knew that it was needed for the variable assignement. Thanks :)